# ZFS cache on same drive (different partition) as /?

Tags: 16.04, mount, hard-drive, disk, zfs

Since upgrading to 16.04 I've moved my /home to a zfs-pool to familiarise myself with zfs.

Already showing its strength it has identified the poor quality of my long running drives:

```
# zpool status -v
  pool: homepool
 state: DEGRADED
status: One or more devices is currently being resilvered.  The pool will
    continue to function, possibly in a degraded state.
action: Wait for the resilver to complete.
  scan: resilver in progress since Sun Oct 16 11:09:17 2016
    402G scanned out of 1,63T at 76,8M/s, 4h41m to go
    401G resilvered, 24,10% done
config:

    NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    homepool    DEGRADED     0     0     0
      mirror-0  DEGRADED     0     0     0
        sdb     UNAVAIL      0     0     0
        sdc     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdd     ONLINE       0     0    1K  (resilvering)
      mirror-1  ONLINE       0     0     0
        sde     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdf     ONLINE       0     0     0
    cache
      sda4      REMOVED      0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

`sdb` has been chugging along for years, but with zfs checksumming it has become apparent that it sometimes produces bad data. Such behaviour is of course not accepted by zfs, which has marked the drive as faulty - which led to me adding `sdd` thus initialising the resilvering.

Now - zfs has removed `sdb` from the pool twice. Both times `sda4` has been removed as well. `sda1` contains my `/`. On both occasions it has been found in a `ro`-state subsequent to the removal of `sdb`.

Is this all connected, or is it more likely I have more than one faulty drive?

My reasoning is that `sdb` is broken, but since it is cached some of the errors might be seen as coming from the cache and since the cache is on the same physical drive as the `/`-partition the root gets nuked when `zfs` tries to recover from errors seen on `sdb` and `sda4` due to both physical drives being marked as garbage producers.

Does that sound likely?

Trying to remount `/` does not work:

```
root@computer:~# df /
-su: /bin/df: Input/output error
root@computer:~# df /de-su: cannot create temp file for here-document: Read-only file system
-su: cannot create temp file for here-document: Read-only file system
^C
root@computer:~# mount | grep sda
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (ro,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)    
root@computer:~# mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda1 /
mount: cannot remount /dev/sda1 read-write, is write-protected
```

EDIT:

Since I added the extra disk (thus removing the sata cd-rom drive) I've not seen the problem.

```
# zpool status -v
  pool: homepool
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 0 in 6h37m with 0 errors on Wed Oct 19 15:23:30 2016
config:

    NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    homepool    ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdb     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdc     ONLINE       0     0     0
        sdd     ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-1  ONLINE       0     0     0 
        sde     ONLINE       0     0     0 
        sdf     ONLINE       0     0     0
    cache
      sda4      ONLINE       0     0     0 

errors: No known data errors
```

All has seemingly been good for almost two weeks, but the broken disk is still there, I'd imagine it should've kept on spewing out garbage data, but it does not seem to.